# Undo problem in Texture painting

Tags: modeling, texturing, texture-painting

I'm having this incredibly frustrating problem. Sometimes when I paint on my texture and press Ctrl+Z for undo, it doesn't undo the paint but rather undo some other action like brush size/properties. And then further undo keeps on undoing every other action but texture paint. It's driving me insane, because I lose my whole texture because being completely unable to undo last action, also it happens very often. I'm not alone in this problem, I saw guys having this issue in discord too. But I haven't found any answer at any place yet. Is this a bug or what?

PS : selecting previous actions from Undo history doesn't work too for some weird reason, you either go way too backwards in painting, or simply don't get to previous state at all.

Comment: What version of Blender are you using, and are you keeping your cursor over the paint area when pressing undo?

Comment: I am using steam version, I believe it's stable version of 2.8. And does putting cursor over paint area affect undo? If it does then it's definitely something I'd keep in mind! Thanks for help

Comment: I am not able to replicate the problem on latest 2.82 build, so I am wondering if this is a bug that was already addressed.

Comment: I'm seeing this problem on build 2.80.75

Comment: @Michael The current stable version is 2.92 if I remember correctly. Why are you using such an old version. I think this issue was a bug in those versions.